# proving that an equation has infinitely many solutions

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

I have the equation $(4n+3)^2-48m^2=1$ that I changed into $X^2-48m^2=1$ so that it would be a Pell's equation, that has infinitely many solutions, that I found being $\left\{\begin{align} 
x_k = \frac{(7+4\sqrt{3} )^k + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^k}{2}\\ 
y_k = \frac{(7+4\sqrt{3})^k - (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^k}{2\cdot4\sqrt{3}} 
\end{align}\right. , k\in\mathbb{N}\quad $
. How can I show that $(4n+3)^2-48m^2=1$ has an infinite numbers of solutions $\equiv3\pmod4$ ?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Which number do you need to be equivalent to $3 \mod 4$?

Comment: Ah yes, I'd want $x_k$ to be $\equiv3\pmod4$. Thanks a lot

Comment: The $x_n's$ satisfy the recursion $x_n=14x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}$, $x_1=7, x_0=1$  the desired claim follows quickly.

Comment: How can I prove that please ?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $7\pm 4\sqrt 3$ is $x^2-14x+1$.  That's essentially the same as the linear recursion I mentioned.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, it all makes sense now !

Comment: Actually, sorry but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I'll a bit of context : I want $\displaystyle\frac{1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2}{n}$ to be equal to a perfect square, that I transformed into $2n^2 - 6m^2 +3n+1=0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $(4n+3)^2-48m^2=1$. 

I then let $X=4n+3$ so that I have a Pell equation $X^2 - 48y^2=1$, the solutions being 
$\left\{\begin{align} 
x_k = \frac{(7+4\sqrt{3} )^k + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^k}{2}\\ 
y_k = \frac{(7+4\sqrt{3})^k - (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^k}{2\cdot4\sqrt{3}} 
\end{align}\right. , k\in\mathbb{N}\quad $

Comment: And, because $X=4n+3$, i have 

$n= \dfrac{(7+4\sqrt{3} )^k + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^k-6}{8}$, 

but I noticed that this solution only works when k is odd, so I have the solutions to $(4n+3)^2-48m^2=1$ being 

$\left\{\begin{align} 
x_k = \frac{(7+4\sqrt{3} )^{2k+1} + (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^{2k+1}-6}{8}\\ 
y_k = \frac{(7+4\sqrt{3})^{2k+1} - (7 - 4\sqrt{3})^{2k+1}}{2\cdot4\sqrt{3}} 
\end{align}\right. , k\in\mathbb{N}\quad $.

How can I prove that there is an infinit number of these solutions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The algebraic numbers $7\pm 4\sqrt 3$ have minimal polynomial $$x^2-14x+1$$

It follows that the $x_k$ and the $y_k$ both satisfy the linear recursion $$a_n=14a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$$

Now, $x_0=1, x_1=7$ and working $\pmod 4$ we see from that recursion that the terms alternate $\pm 1\pmod 4$. Thus there are infinitely many $x_n$ of each type.